# How to create a gridded field in Python that contains the country name of each pixel globally with a resolution of 0.1°x0.1°?

Tags: python-3.x, reverse-geocoding

I need a gridded field of the whole world with 0.1°x0.1° resolution. Each pixel should contain the country's name the pixel is in.

I have tried to produce the field using the reverse_geocode package in Python. The problem is, when you enter a location in international waters, the package provides the name of the nearest country, and not simply "international waters" (see example code below). I have also considered using google, but I suppose with more than six million pixels to be determined, a commercial service might not be the best choice.

```
import reverse_geocode as rg

# coordinates in atlantic ocean
lat_water = 35
lon_water = -29

coordinates = [(lat_water, lon_water)]
result = rg.search(coordinates)

country = result[0]['country']

print('expected: international waters')
print('from geocode:', country)

# output
# expected: international waters
# from geocode: Portugal
```

Is there a way to do this without using an external dataset that might contain an ocean/no ocean mask at my target resolution?

Comment: Maybe you can create issue on `reverse_geocode`'s github repository, usually author can direct you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using cartopy might do the job:

```
import numpy as np
import shapely
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader

shpfilename = shpreader.natural_earth(
    resolution='50m', category='cultural', name='admin_0_countries')

reader = shpreader.Reader(shpfilename)

cs = list(reader.records())
for lon in np.arange(-179.9, -180.1, 0.1):                                                                                                                                     
    for lat in np.arange(-90, 90.1, 0.1):
        c = list(set([_c.attributes["NAME_EN"] for _c in cs if _c.geometry.contains(shapely.geometry.Point(lon,lat))]))
        if len(c) == 0:
            print(f"{lat:5.1f}, {lon:5.1f} nothing")
        else:
            assert len(c) == 1
            print(f"{lat:5.1f}, {lon:5.1f} {c[0]}")
```

Not very optimized, but should do the job.